# How to code coverage for the inner functions using Jasmine.js in v 1.31.?

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine, karma-runner, jasmine-jquery

I have Backbone view function like :

```
functionName: function(parameter){          
       if(parameter == 1){    
          callSomeOtherFunction1();
       }else if(parameter == 2){
           callSomeOtherFunction2()
       }else if(parameter == 3){
           callSomeOtherFunction3()
       }else if(parameter == 4){
           callSomeOtherFunction4()
       }else if(parameter == 5){
           callSomeOtherFunction5()
       }else{
           callDefaultFunction();
       }
  }
```

Or,

```
functionName: function(parameter){      
   switch(parameter){    
       case 1: callSomeOtherFunction1(); break;
       case 2: callSomeOtherFunction2(); break;
       case 3: callSomeOtherFunction3(); break;
       case 4: callSomeOtherFunction4(); break;
       case 5: callSomeOtherFunction5(); break;
       case 6: callSomeOtherFunction6(); break;
       default: callDefaultFunction; break;
   }
}

callSomeOtherFunction1:  function(){
 // callSomeOtherFunction1 function logic goies here...
}

callSomeOtherFunction2:  function(){
 // callSomeOtherFunction2 function logic goies here...
}
...
...

etc.
```

I need to write a test cases to cover all of these inner function calls using Jasmine framework version 1.3.1?

When I am tryin to call this function **functionName** with parameter between 1- 6, **only one of the inner function is covered**,

But How to (Code) cover all of these inner functions are callable (working) for improving code coverage percentage in Karma Test Runner?.

Answer (score 0):

functionName() must be accessible from outside the object. Below, I call the object it's attached to "some_object". Here's how you would test it:

```
    describe('test functionName', function () {

        it('expect callSomeOtherFunction1 to be called', function () {
            spyOn(some_object, 'callSomeOtherFunction1');
            some_object.functionName(1);

            expect(some_object.callSomeOtherFunction1).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        it('expect callSomeOtherFunction2 to be called', function () {
            spyOn(some_object, 'callSomeOtherFunction1');
            some_object.functionName(2);

            expect(some_object.callSomeOtherFunction2).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        ...
        ...
    });
```